# ordenamiento alfabetico

Tags: c++

Guardé un listado de nombres, los ordené alfabéticamente y luego los imprima, pero no me compila.

El código es en C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstring>

    int n=0;
    int ia,ja,ka;
    int l=0;

int main(void){

    printf("¿cuantos nombres deseas anotar?");
    scanf(" %d", &n );
    char *nombres[n];
    char *temp;
    
    for(int i=0; i<=n-1; i++){
        
        printf("coloque el nombre numero %0.1d : \n", i+1);
        scanf(" %[^\n]s ", &nombres[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<=n-1; i++){
    
        printf("\n %s \n", &nombres[i]);
    }
    
    for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++ ){
        for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++ ){
            float opc;
            opc= strcmp(nombres[j], nombres[i]);
            printf(" %f ",opc);
            if (opc > 0) {
                temp = nombres[j];
                nombres[j] = nombres[i];
                nombres[i] = temp;
            }
        }

    printf( "Lista ordenada:\n" );
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++ )
        printf( "  %[^\n]", nombres[i] );
    }
return 0;

}
```

La primera parte también me genera un error, no me deja leer mas de 8 caracteres, se enciman en los anteriores

Comment: Hola, seria bueno que también agregaras el mensaje de tu error, así te podemos ayudar mas facil.

Comment: ¿Ese código compila sin errores? No debería porque estás definiendo un array de punteros a char, usando una variable aquí: `char* nombres[n]`. Un array así definido se crea en tiempo de compilación y en ese momento no se sabe el valor de `n`.

Comment: "*El código es en C++*". Mentira.

Answer (score 2):

**VLA**

En C++, la dimensión de los arrays tienen que ser conocida en tiempo de compilación es decir,hablamos de literales en el código:

```
char array[100];
```

Sin embargo, en tu caso el tamaño del array viene dado por una variable:

```
int n;
char *nombres[n];
```

Esto que tu tienes se conoce como VLA, "*Variable Length Array*" y es una característica que no está soportada por el estándar de C++. Te funciona porque tu compilador te ofrece esta opción, pero yo de ti no la usaría por varias razones:

1. Los arrays se declaran en la pila del programa, la pila tiene un tamaño limitado y, si se llena, tu programa se muere. Abusar de arrays en la pila solo sirve para que la recursividad máxima que admite tu programa se vea seriamente limitada
2. No es una característica soportada por el estándar, luego tu código puede no compilar al usar otros compiladores
3. Crear arrays de esta manera dificulta la aplicación de optimizaciones por parte del copmpilador y reutilización del código

Si necesitas un array cuyo tamaño viene determinado por una variable, usa `new`:

```
char **nombres = new char*[n];
```

**Array no inicializado**

Volviendo a tu código, fíjate que, haciendo uso de VLA, has declarado un array de punteros a `char`, pero ¿A dónde apuntan esos punteros?

```
char *nombres[n];

for(int i=0; i<=n-1; i++){
    
    printf("coloque el nombre numero %0.1d : \n", i+1);
    scanf(" %[^\n]s ", &nombres[i]);
}
```

Es decir la línea `char *nombres[n]` crea, en memoria, una estructura tal que:

```
|0x00|0x01|0x02|0x03|0x04|0x05|0x06|0x07|0x08|0x09|...
|       char*       |       char*       |       char*
^ nombres
```

Entonces, cada elemento de `nombres` será un puntero. Un puntero es una variable cuya finalidad es almacenar direcciones de memoria. Por otro lado tenemos que C++ no inicializa por defecto ninguna variable, es decir, si únicamente declaramos una variable, lo que hace C++ es reservarle la memoria necesaria en la pila ... y ya. El contenido de esa memoria se corresponde con valores almacenados previamente en esa misma región de memoria por otras variables que ya no existen.

Resumiendo, cada uno de los punteros de `nombres` almacena un valor aleatorio por defecto, es decir, apuntan a direcciones de memoria aleatorias.

Tu programa se limita entonces a escribir valores en esas posiciones de memoria aleatorias, las cuales, muy seguramente, no pertenezcan a regiones de memoria de tu programa. Lo que sucede entonces, en un Sistema Operativo moderno, es que el propio Sistema Operativo detecta el acceso no autorizado a la memoria y mata tu proceso para evitar que corrompas la memoria de otros procesos y aplicaciones... ya has encontrado el motivo por el que tu programa se muere sin más.

La solución, como ya se ha comentado muchas veces en StackOverflow, pasa por hacer que esos punteros direccionen posiciones de memoria válidas:

```
char **nombres = new char*[n];
for( int i=0; i<n; i++ )
{
  nombres[i] = new char[31]; // Capacidad para 30 caracteres
}
```

Por supuesto, toda llamada a `new` debe tener su correspondiente `delete` cuando ya no sea necesaria esa memoria:

```
for( int i=0; i<n; i++ )
{
  delete[] nombres[i];
}
delete[] nombres;
```

**Uso incorrecto de arrays**

```
for(int i=0; i<=n-1; i++){
    printf("coloque el nombre numero %0.1d : \n", i+1);
    scanf(" %[^\n]s ", &nombres[i]);
}
```

Como bien sabes, `scanf` necesita que le pases la dirección de memoria de las variables a modificar. El problema que hay es que los arrays son especiales en ese aspecto. Un array es una variable que almacena una dirección de memoria y esa dirección de memoria es la que tienes que pasarle a `scanf`, ya que es ahí donde se encuentran los datos... es decir, ese `&` sobra:

```
for(int i=0; i<=n-1; i++){
    printf("coloque el nombre numero %0.1d : \n", i+1);
    scanf(" %[^\n]s ", nombres[i]);
}
```

Y lo mismo pasa con `printf`. El flag `%s` necesita que se le facilite un puntero al inicio de la cadena a imprimir y tu le estás pasando otra cosa:

```
for(int i=0; i<=n-1; i++){

    printf("\n %s \n", &nombres[i]); // mal
    printf("\n %s \n", nombres[i]);  // bien
}
```

**Flags incorrectos**

Volvemos al bucle de lectura:

```
for(int i=0; i<=n-1; i++){
    
    printf("coloque el nombre numero %0.1d : \n", i+1);
    scanf(" %[^\n]s ", &nombres[i]);
}
```

`i` es una variable de tipo `int`, es decir, un tipo entero, sin decimales. ¿Por qué intentas formatear este tipo para que te muestre un decimal? No tiene sentido alguno.

Corregido quedaría así:

```
    printf("coloque el nombre numero %d : \n", i+1);
```

De la misma forma, el último `printf` es igualmente incorrecto:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++ )
    printf( "  %[^\n]", nombres[i] );
}
```

¿Qué es lo que tiene que mostrar exactmente `printf`? Se te ha olvidado indicar el tipo de valor a imprimir... además que en el caso de `printf` no hay que decirle que pare en el salto de línea:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++ )
    printf( "  %s", nombres[i] );
}
```

Y bueno, con esto el programa ya no se muere pero sigue dando algún problema... intenta encontrar su origen por tu cuenta, que es como se aprende.